# Android | fatal error: GLES/gl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wall
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I run....

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=./ APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk
```

and I get....

> Compile thumb  : test <= test.c
>
> ./test.c:8:29: fatal error: GLES/gl.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/test/test.o] Error 1

Now I am guessing adding a cflag of -I/include or a C_Include in the Android.mk will work but shouldn't that be handled by the -lGLESv1_CM.

Comment: -l is linker flag, the error you get is at compile time.  you might want to check if GLES/gl.h is in your BUILD_SHARED_LIBARAY path variable?

Comment: try "LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libEGL libGLESv1_CM"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making an Application.mk file worked for me....

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```